# How could i type this so that the array with string or number constructor can be typed into s or n as either string or number

Tags: typescript, types

example code with which im stuck with said typing implementation.

Is there a way to do this since i need it in function inside array that is params

```
type Pattern<T extends StringConstructor | NumberConstructor> = [T, T extends StringConstructor ? (val: string) => string : (val: number) => number];

function match(
  value: string | number,
  patterns: Pattern<any>[],
) {
  for (const [p, h] of patterns) {
    if (value.constructor === p) {
      return h(value);
    }
  }
  throw new Error("No matching pattern found.");
}

const patterns = [
  [String, (s) => s.length], // Pattern for String
  [Number, (n) => n + 1],   // Pattern for Number
];

//@ts-ignore
const testingResult = match(123456, patterns);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not annotating `patterns` as being of type `Pattern[]`?  I'd change the definition of `Pattern` to be a union and not a generic, and fix some errors in your code in `--strict` mode, but the main thing is annotating `patterns` or giving the compiler some advance warning you'd like it to be seen as an array of `Pattern`s. See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3oJ3m).  Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: (see prev comment and pls reply) Aside: it's very unusual to compare against the `String` or `Number` constructor this way; I would expect a `typeof` type guard.  And given the particular example code I'm not sure why you'd want to look things up in an array instead of an object.  That is, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXynON).  But this is all aside and maybe you have some use case that motivates this approach?

Comment: Hey, so yea h this is for pattern matching code for a library my friend is working on,he said he HAS to use those constructors and pattern 2d array like that.

when it come to that playground link, `s` and `n` aren't infered since yea you manually added types to them inside their func param in the array,which is something that he request me to make "automatic",he claimed you could make it that patterns would use 0th element and use it to infer that function's param with typeof value so either string/number

Comment: I'm not sure how to deal with your friend's assertion; the only way that would work is if `Pattern` were a discriminated union, but `StringConstructor`/`NumberConstructor` is not a valid discriminant type.  Can you not just annotate the callback param?  You could make helper functions like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1QBkw) shows.  Does that work for your needs?

Comment: yea the issue at hand is he wanted it to be automatically inferred because he wants to support pattern matching on everything,he's building library of some sorts,and so he was curious if its possible to cast it in a way where 0th element would be used to infer onto functions param but ofc in a way where you go from constructor to said primitive

Comment: But thank you for trying anyway,i believe his approach is way to complicated for what he's trying to accomplish

Comment: So then it's essentially impossible without refactoring.  I'll write up an answer saying so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want

```
const patterns = [
  [String, s => s.length],
  [Number, n => n + 1]  
];
```

to have the type of `s` and `n` [contextually inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing), you have to give `patterns` or the initializing expression a type in which there is appropriate context for `s` and `n`.  Unfortunately, since presumably you'd like the patterns to appear in any order, the type you need for the array elements looks like

```
type Pattern =
  readonly [StringConstructor, (x: string) => number] |
  readonly [NumberConstructor, (x: number) => number];
```

which is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) but *not* a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  (Because `StringConstructor` and `NumberConstructor` are not [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).)  That means if you write `[String, s => s.length]`, the compiler cannot use `String` to narrow to just the first union member, and thus does not provide the context you need for `s` to be inferred.

So there's essentially no way to do it without refactoring in some fashion.

---

For example, you could make the patterns an actual discriminated union type (and not [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) at least until [microsoft/TypeScript#55632](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55632) is fixed):

```
type Pattern =
  { p: "string", h: (x: string) => number } |
  { p: "number", h: (x: number) => number };
```

And then it starts working (as long as you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `patterns` to provide the context):

```
const patterns: Pattern[] = [
  { p: "string", h: s => s.length },
  { p: "number", h: n => n + 1 }
];
```

But you need to refactor the implementation of `match`

```
function match(
  value: string | number,
  patterns: readonly Pattern[],
) {
  const ctorLookup = { string: String, number: Number }
  for (const { p, h } of patterns) {
    if (value.constructor = ctorLookup[p]) {
      return h(value as never);
    }
  }
  throw new Error("No matching pattern found.");
}

const testingResult = match(123456, patterns);
```

---

Or you could keep the current typings and just provide helper functions to produce `Pattern` instances:

```
type Pattern =
  readonly [StringConstructor, (x: string) => number] |
  readonly [NumberConstructor, (x: number) => number];

const strPattern = (p: (s: string) => number): Pattern => [String, p];
const numPattern = (p: (s: number) => number): Pattern => [Number, p];
```

Which also works:

```
const patterns = [strPattern(s => s.length), numPattern(n => n + 1)];

const testingResult = match(123456, patterns);
```

---

I'll stop enumerating possibilities now; the point is: either you need to annotate `s` and `n` manually, or you have to refactor somehow.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)